# How do I encode only id in the URL in PHP?

Tags: php, url, urlencode

```
<a class='btn btn-success' href='../posts/postview.php?id=".urlencode($row['category_id'])."'role='button'>See Posts</a></td>
```

here is my button url but this urlencode method doesn`t return any encoded id. Instead it returns the exact same id in Numeric. What do I do???

I have tried this. but haven`t get any results. I am expecting numeric id in the URL should be encoded.

Comment: As what should a number be encoded? The ID is a number - correct?

Comment: If the ID is a number then there is no encoding needed. Give us an example of an ID you're testing with,  and explain what output you expected to see after encoding, and why. Then we can understand what you really mean.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of URL encoding in PHP, it's important to clarify that you don't need to encode alphanumeric characters (including numbers) for URLs. PHP's `urlencode` function performs specific encoding based on [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

> Returns a string in which all **non-alphanumeric** characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It is encoded the same way that the posted data from a WWW form is encoded, that is the same way as in application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type. This differs from the » RFC 3986 encoding (see rawurlencode()) in that for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs.

In your scenario, there's no need to manually encode alphanumeric characters. So the below example should work for you:

```html
<a class='btn btn-success' href='../posts/postview.php?id=".$row['category_id']."' role='button'>See Posts</a></td>
```